# converting times from character to time variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to pinpoint where the errors lie in the records.
When I run a view A down to 4 records, then input that view into another view B, I get this error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character strings.

Time is a separate field than date.
I do not care to add the time field to the date field.
I am looking to subtract hours/minutes from an end time minus a start time and show the result as hours:minutes.

However when I run each of those 4 records with separate WHERE clause based on that id#, from View A, I never get the error message in view B. Why is this? I am trying to isolate the bad time.

View A code:

```
CASE WHEN LEFT(endtime,2) > 23 THEN CAST('23' + RIGHT(endtime, 3) AS TIME) WHEN endtime = '' THEN '23:59:00' ELSE CAST(endtime AS TIME) 
END AS Newendtime, 
CASE WHEN LEFT(starttime,2) > 23 THEN CAST('23' + RIGHT(starttime, 3) AS TIME) WHEN   starttime = '' THEN '23:59:00' ELSE CAST(starttime AS TIME) 
END AS NewStarttime,
```

I have times of:

```
    start  end

    17:45 19:45
    20:55 15:39
    16:18 16:45
    0:10  11:15
```

It appears `0:10` is the culprit. but when I only output that one record out of view A, it runs fine through view B. Even more bizarre is when I add another where clause to view A which still outputs the same records, I don't get the error in view b.

View B has a WHERE clause

```
WHERE        (NewendTime <> NewstartTime)
```

When I take out the WHERE clause it runs, leave it in, I get the error.

EDIT:

I see the left statement looking at the colon `:`. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you identified, looking at the left 2 characters won't work because there are not always two characters before the colon. Why not just cast the fields as they are today as times? They all look like they should be valid. I don't think there is any need to perform those case statements.

```
SELECT 
    CAST([start] AS TIME) AS NewStartTime,
    CAST([end] AS TIME) AS NewStartTime
FROM 
    #times
```

Comment: Those 4 records are a subset of a large file of 2000 records going in which is itself a view of 100,000 record table. Those 4/2000 still crash the error message. There are times when the data entry program allows for times greater than 23:59 on the clock which is incorrect to us out here in data land "24:50" is changed to 23:50.  Also blanks are allowed which I am also changing to 23:59

Comment: My feeling is that error messages are not restricted to the view set you lay out there, that the validity of dates from character is somehow starting at the 100,000 table level. Probably not the case though.